# UIPicker dark color ios13 :

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipickerview

I am facing issue with very old developed App, my UIPicker looks black in ios13 but in ios12 it looks good.

Image from ios12 :

[image]

Image from ios13 :

[image]

Just to confirm that

1 : **When i am checking Dark mode is OFF**

2 : **I have not set background color for UIpicker it is the default color**

I have tried to search the similar issue but not one face the issue, even in my App also it comes randomly

Any one who face the same issue?
Any idea suggestion are most welcome!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: yes you can set `Dark mode is disable` on that particular controller.

Answer (score 2):

@guru Try like in your Objective C

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    self.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
}
```

either you can try like below too on your AppDelegate.m,

```
    if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    self.window.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = UIUserInterfaceStyleLight;
}
```

Comment: @guru It's just a dark mode disable action.

Comment: @guru I have updated my answer. Could try the second one too and let me know.

Comment: I got  Property 'window' not found on object of type  "ViewController"

Comment: @guru you need to add that on your AppDelegate class

Comment: Done, result is same, it does not look issue of dark mode As i mention my dark mode is Off.

Comment: @guru Then you need to check have you set clear color to uidatePicker's superView tint color or background color?

Comment: I have set background color of UIPicker

Comment: What happen if you comment the line?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to either add `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` in your viewControlled 
or set `UIUserInterfaceStyle` to Light in info.plist

Comment: overrideUserInterfaceStyle what it means? my project is in objective C

Comment: I tried UIUserInterfaceStyle to Light in info.plist but result is same, my dark mode is also off.